# Does Google FileStore work with Windows containers on GKE?

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, windows-container, google-cloud-filestore

I referred the below link from GCP
https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/accessing-fileshares . Created a Filestore instance followed by a pv & pvc as mentioned in the example. 
When I deployed my pod (windows container), I have observed the mount did not happen & I didn't get any errors as well.

When I write any data into the mount path volume & delete the pod, the expectation is data remains persistent but that is not happening here. Can any one help me out here please.

Comment: Have you checked if this is works with different OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work for Windows containers on GKE yet. We are actively working on it.